# How to create a resource route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I create a controller named **HomeController** and their methods named

```
getIndex()
```

and

```
index()
```

and after that i make a routing  is follows

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

But it will gives me this error

```
Controller method not found.
```

I have fine working in this routes

```
Route::controller('/', 'IndexController');
```

Please help

**Update**
Thanks all for your help..
I am a beginner to laravel. So I made a big mistake in my routing that I forget about first in first out rule. So I have to reorder my routes from

```
Route::controller('/', 'IndexController'); 
Route::resource('homes', 'HomesController');
```

to

```
Route::resource('homes', 'HomesController');
Route::controller('/', 'IndexController');
```

Comment: How do you call your controller? http://app.tld/home/ ?

Comment: @ ManiacTwister http://localhost:82/home will call HomeController

Comment: Visting (a GET request) to `localhost:82/methodnamehere` would call `ControllerName@getMethodnamehere` where a POST request to `localhost:82/methodnamehere` would call `ControllerName@postMethodnamehere`

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating controller manually check out that you extend BaseController class.

You can install https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Jeffrey Way's Laravel command line utilities and with one command:

```
php artisan generate:resource
```

You'll have complete REST-ful resource generated - from routes to models and controllers and even migration table.

Comment: I believe you meant `php artisan generate:resource ResourceName` rather than `generate:migration` but yes. Jeffery Way's Generators are a **must** for L4 development. The first time I actually used `generate:resource` I was just left with my mouth open :O ........

Comment: @carousel Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594340/how-can-i-implement-resource-controllers-if-i-use-many-get-on-the-laravel

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a resource controller, you will only need the "index" method. Given your route, you would have to enter: yourdomain.com/home in order to get to the index of Home Controller. If you would like to use the same index method as the home page you would need to add this to your routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Also, make (if you haven't already) run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this as well :

```
php artisan controller:make HomeController
```

In your terminal!

Answer (score 1):

To create a resourceful controller you should run the following `artisan` command from your terminal/command prompt

```
php artisan controller:make HomeController
```

This will create a resourceful controller inside your `controllers` folder, if you want, you may provide a path as an option of the command like

```
php artisan controller:make HomeController --path="app/controllers/admin"
```

It'll create a resourceful controller with `7` methods and to view the routes mapping for each method you may run the `routes` command from terminal/command prompt like

```
php artisan routes
```

This command will show the table of all routes and action/url and name each route uses, so you can find out the proper `url` or `route name` for each actions/methods in your resourceful comtroller.

If you declare a route using `Route::controller('/', 'IndexController');` then you have to create the `IndexController` manually and in this controller (RESTfull) you can create methods using `http` verbs (`GET`, `POST` etc) as prefix like

```
public function getIndex()
{
    //
}
```

For this action/method, your url will be `IndexController` and it should be a normal `GET` request from address bar.

To submit a form you may declare a post method like:

```
public function postSave()
{
    //
}
```

So, you can submit a form to this action/method using `POST` method in the form and the action for the form would be `http://example.com/save`, without the verb. You can always, run the `php artisan routes` command to find out the `url/route name` for a controller method/function. For more information, check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

you should go to the Providers/RouteServiceProviders and change this method to the:

```
    public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')

            **->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')**

            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```