# How can I implement Resource Controllers if I use many "get" on the laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, resources, laravel-5.6

I have routes laravel like this :

```
Route::prefix('member')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::prefix('purchase')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/', 'Member\PurchaseController@index')->name('member.purchase.index');
        Route::get('order', 'Member\PurchaseController@order')->name('member.purchase.order');
        Route::get('transaction', 'Member\PurchaseController@transaction')->name('member.purchase.transaction');
    });
});
```

My controller like this :

```
<?php
...
class PurchaseController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function index()
    {
        ...
    }
    public function order()
    {
        ...
    }
    public function transaction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to change it to Resource Controllers(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers)

So I only use 1 routes

From my case, my routes to be like this :

```
Route::prefix('member')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('purchase', 'Member\PurchaseController');
});
```

If I using resouce controller, I only can data in the index method or show method

How can I get data in order method and transaction method?

Comment: `Route::resource` is for pre-defined index, create, store, show, edit, update and delete methods. if you want to use custom methods (like you used here), you need to declare them individually.

Comment: @Success Man So do you think it is not suitable to use resource controller for my case?

Comment: For custom functions, you need to define each route.

Answer (score 3):

You could try like this, Just put your resource controller custom method up resource route.

```
Route::prefix('member')->middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('order', 'Member\PurchaseController@order')->name('member.purchase.order');
    Route::get('transaction', 'Member\PurchaseController@transaction')->name('member.purchase.transaction')
    Route::resource('purchase', 'Member\PurchaseController');
});
```

Comment: This is the best way. You can override any route resource by adding it above the resource call. In all web.php and api.php it is first come, first serve.

Comment: Perhaps  you want to explain why this happens? When creating a resource controller for `purchase`, it will define a route with a catch all param on `/purchase/{purchase}`, which is the route to view a single purchase by identifier. Since the resource route does not define what type of data this is, it will match every GET request on `/purchase/xxxx`, including order and transaction if those routes are defined **after** the resource route.

Comment: @MD Iyasin Arafat Why order and transaction are out of group purchase? I want the order and transaction to be in group purchase

Comment: @Success Man, Then you just remove 'member' from your naming and then run 'php artisan route:list' to see route group.

Answer (score 2):

For the resource controller, it is pre-defined by the Laravel, which contain only the 7 method.

Shown at below table.

[image: Action handled by resource controller]

So, if you want any other method, you have to definde by youself.

```
php artisan route:list
```

You can use this to check all the route you defined.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers on here are pretty much correct.

From my other answer you linked this question in from, here that way based on what *MD Iyasin Arafat* has suggested, **if you are using laravel 5.5+**:

```
# Group all routes requiring middleware auth, thus declared only once

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){

    # Suffix rules in group for prefix,namespace & name with "member"

    Route::namespace('Member')->prefix('member')->name('member.')->group(function () {

            Route::get('purchase/order', 'PurchaseController@order')->name('purchase.order');
            Route::get('purchase/transaction', 'PurchaseController@transaction')->name('purchase.transaction');
            Route::resource('purchase', 'PurchaseController');

    });

});
```

**Grouping Methods** ( *->group()* ) :

---

**Controller Namespace** ( *->namespace('Member')* )

> Prepends to **'PurchaseController'** to give
>   **'Member\PurchaseController'**

---

**Route Name** (*->name('member.')*)

> Prepends to **name('purchase.order')** to give
>   **route('member.purchase.order')**

---

**URI Request** (*->prefix('member')*)

> Prepends to **/purchase** to give **example.com/member/purchase**

As you can see, using the methods above with group() reduces repetition of prefix declarations.

**Hint**

> **Custom routes** must always be declared **before** a **resource** never after!

Example to use if you have a lot of custom routes for Purchase Controller and how a second controller looks for member group:

```
# Group all routes requiring middleware auth, thus declared only once

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){

    # Suffix rules in group for prefix,namespace & name with "member"

    Route::namespace('Member')->prefix('member')->name('member.')->group(function () {

            Route::prefix('purchase')->name('purchase.')->group(function() {

                Route::get('order', 'PurchaseController@order')->name('order');

                Route::get('transaction', 'PurchaseController@transaction')->name('transaction');

                Route::get('history', 'PurchaseController@history')->name('history');

                Route::get('returns', 'PurchaseController@returns')->name('returns');

                Route::get('status', 'PurchaseController@status')->name('status');

                Route::resource('/', 'PurchaseController');

            });

            Route::prefix('account')->name('account.')->group(function() {

                Route::get('notifications', 'AccountController@notifications')->name('notifications');

                Route::resource('/', 'AccountController');

            });

    });

});
```

Comment: Why order and transaction are out of group purchase? I want the order and transaction to be in group purchase

Comment: You don't really need to create another nested group unless you are going to have a lot of custom functions for /purchase/*, I have added an example of such further nestings to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I fixed the upper example, I forgot to manually inline prefix the nested gets with purchase/